# iterating over an STL container using element keys

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, stl

I need some help with choosing an efficient algorithm to put elements from a vector into presorted buckets - or ideally output iterator ranges (as they are efficient I think).  The example below is totally contrived, but the idea is that a an element's key is used to determine the output bucket.  I'm not asking how to sort in order as that is a very simple matter of simply calling (which works and reorders the elements according to the key)

```
std::sort(testVec.begin(), testVec.end(), comparator);
```

I put a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/341294003780728f) on coliru, where it is very easy to modify and fix (well not that easy or I wouldn't be asking the question). I could also go through the elements in this sorted list and while the key value is the same, append it into a new bucket, but I am looking for something more STL like in nature, and right now the above smells like a bit of a last resort hack, also the final solution needs to be efficient as the testVec is potentially large and the objects are also big in size.  I would prefer not to modify the testvec - so it should be immutable.

Ideally I am looking for some sort of construct that spits out range iterators or something equally efficient.  The actual objects are large so passing references or moving them is really the only option - my actual objects (the equivalent to MyStr) are movable.  Something sort of foreach key, apply key predicate or something which I cannot figure out is what I am looking for.  I hard coded the 3 buckets below just to show what I need to be able to attain - this is totally a hack.

Thanks in advance for any help with this problem

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct MyStr
{
    int key;
    std::string strval;

    MyStr(int key, const std::string& rStrVal) 
        : key(key)
        , strval(rStrVal) 
    {}

    // let stream operators be friend functions instead of members!
    inline friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MyStr& val) {
        os << "key[" << val.key << "], strval['" << val.strval << "']";
        return os;
    }

    bool operator < (const MyStr& str) const {
        return (key > str.key);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector <MyStr> testVec = {
        MyStr(4, "key 4"), 
        MyStr(3, "key 3"), 
        MyStr(3, "key 3"), 
        MyStr(2, "key 2"), 
        MyStr(2, "key 2"), 
        MyStr(2, "key 2")
    };

    //auto comparator = [](const MyStr& lhs, const MyStr& rhs) {
    //    return lhs.key < rhs.key;
    //};

    std::vector <MyStr> foursBucket;
    std::vector <MyStr> threesBucket;
    std::vector <MyStr> twosBucket;

    auto ostriter = std::ostream_iterator<MyStr>(std::cout, ",");
    std::for_each(testVec.begin(), testVec.end(), 
        [&](const MyStr& next){
            switch (next.key) {
            case 4:
                foursBucket.push_back(next);
                break;
            case 3:
                threesBucket.push_back(next);
                break;
            case 2:
                twosBucket.push_back(next);
                break;
            }
        });
    std::cout << "Elements with Key Value 2" << std::endl;
    std::copy(twosBucket.begin(), twosBucket.end(), ostriter);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Elements with Key Value 3" << std::endl;
    std::copy(threesBucket.begin(), threesBucket.end(), ostriter);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Elements with Key Value 4" << std::endl;
    std::copy(foursBucket.begin(), foursBucket.end(), ostriter);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

produces the following output

```
Elements with Key Value 2
key[2], strval['key 2'],key[2], strval['key 2'],key[2], strval['key 2'],
Elements with Key Value 3
key[3], strval['key 3'],key[3], strval['key 3'],
Elements with Key Value 4
key[4], strval['key 4'],
```

As you can see the structure is very simple and I've shown how I can currently sort the objects using a predicate but I do not know which of the plethora of algorithms to choose from to efficiently iterate over

Comment: Could it be that you are simply looking for something like `std::multiset`? It will be a single container and storage will not be continuous, but I don't understand what you need different containers for if you can simply store iterator ranges.

Comment: I need to be able to process each of these separate ranges separately - that is why I had the separate buckets.  Ideally If I could call some magic predicate -r lambda function which had the input range as its argument, I would be done, the idea that the preducate would be called as many times as there were unique keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for an [`unordered_multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap). It is an unordered associative container that'll place the key-value pairs into buckets depending on the hash value of the key (`int` in the following example).

```
std::unordered_multimap<int, std::string> 
    mymap{{4, "key 4"}, 
          {3, "key 3"}, 
          {3, "key 3"}, 
          {2, "key 2"}, 
          {2, "key 2"}, 
          {2, "key 2"},
         };

for(auto const& kv : mymap) {
    std::cout << "key: " << kv.first << " value: " << kv.second << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
key: 2 value: key 2
key: 2 value: key 2
key: 2 value: key 2
key: 3 value: key 3
key: 3 value: key 3
key: 4 value: key 4
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d777f734069c1f3a)

---

In the comment below you clarified that you receive a `vector<MyStr>` input, and the container type cannot be changed. In that case, use [`std::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) to find all the elements containing a particular key.

```
// comparator for equal_range
struct comp
{
    bool operator()(int key, MyStr const& m) const { return m.key < key; }
    bool operator()(MyStr const& m, int key) const { return key < m.key; }
};

// sort the vevctor
std::sort(testVec.begin(), testVec.end());

// search for all elements with key=2
auto range = std::equal_range(testVec.begin(), testVec.end(), 2, comp());

for(auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it) {
    std::cout << "key: " << it->key << " value: " << it->strval << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
key: 2 value: key 2
key: 2 value: key 2
key: 2 value: key 2
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c14787b639c7bdd)

---

To iterate over each unique key, the easiest way is to use `std::unique_copy` to create a new container that holds only elements that have unique keys. Then iterate over this container and use `equal_range` on each key.

```
bool operator==(MyStr const& m1, MyStr const& m2) { return m1.key == m2.key; }

// sort the vevctor
std::sort(testVec.begin(), testVec.end());

std::vector<MyStr> unique_keys;
std::unique_copy(testVec.begin(), testVec.end(), std::back_inserter(unique_keys));

for(auto const& u : unique_keys) {
    std::cout << "Searching for key: " << u.key << '\n';
    auto range = std::equal_range(testVec.begin(), testVec.end(), u.key, comp());

    for(auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it) {
        std::cout << "key: " << it->key << " value: " << it->strval << '\n';
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25fd53390404bbf0)

If the elements are expensive to copy, and you'd rather avoid having to create a new container holding unique elements, you could create your own output iterator that mimics [`std::back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator). Its `operator=` implementation will take a `MyStr const&` argument, but `push_back` only the key from the argument into the unique key container, which would be `vector<int>` in that case.

Another approach (that I'm not certain will work) that you can use to avoid modifying the input range, and avoid copying the elements to a new range, is to create `vector<MyStr *>`, where each element points to the corresponding element in the original range. Then repeat all the steps above, except, instead of passing `vector::iterator`s to the algorithms, use [`boost::indirect_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html). This iterator will apply an extra level of dereferencing to the pointers in your container, and the algorithms should then work as if they were operating on `vector<MyStr>` instead.

Comment: Thank you praetorian, but the actual input to my function is a fixed vector<MyStr> of elements with a sortable key.  Ideally if I could have some lambda callback around this vector whereby it got called multiple times with a begin/end range parameter that corresponded to elements with a particular key, I would be done.  I have no idea how to do that efficiently.

Comment: @johnco3 Sorry, I didn't understand your question correctly. I've updated the answer using `equal_range` to find all the elements having a particular key.

Comment: A real improvement! - I think you are almost there, but I also need to have an outer loop that looks for all unique keys (in the case above you hard code 2) and then I can call your solution in an inner loop, its like I need to call std::unique or something and iterate over the keys from the resultant collection, however that requires that the collection be pre-sorted and that is not an option as the std::vector is a const& and if I would prefer to avoid copying the elements

Comment: @johnco3 `equal_range` requires the input range to be partitioned with respect to the element you're searching for, which, in your case, since you're searching for all keys, means the input range needs to be sorted. `unique(_copy)` requires the entire range to be sorted. You might be able to get away with not copying all the elements, but instead creating a `vector<MyStr *>` where each element points to the corresponding element from the input range. Then use `boost::indirect_iterator` to do everything I'm doing above (not sure if that approach will work).

Comment: @johnco3 Finally, if you'd written both your comments above at the beginning of the question, it would've been answered by now. Instead of describing what you *wanted to do*, you described [*everything you'd tried so far*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Be careful not to fall into that trap the next time (it's very easy to).

Comment: my apologies, I actually only thought of the std::unique thing after I saw your comment.  Sorry if my comments have been distracting, but to give me my due, I did explicitly state that the testVec should be immutable, thanks for being patient, and I really do appreciate your clear and concise responses.

Comment: @johnco3 I see that you did say the input must not be modified now. Sorry that I missed it the first time. Anyway, I hope the last solution and suggestions work for you.